# Soma dos valores de uma coluna do BD entre um intervalo de tempo - PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, data

```
include "conexao.inc";

$sql="SELECT * FROM tb_abastece WHERE data BETWEEN ('20/01/2019') AND ('30/01/2019')";          
$res=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql); 

while($vreg=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $id=$vreg[0];
    $ida=$vreg[1];
    $postoa=$vreg[2];
    $insumoa=$vreg[3];
    $valora=$vreg[4];
    $kmlta=$vreg[5];
    $dataa=$vreg[6];
    $ltsa=$vreg[7];
    $destinoa=$vreg[8];
    $odometroa=$vreg[9];
    $kma=$vreg[10];
}
<div>
    echo $id." / ".$postoa." // ".$kmlta."  // ".$destinoa; 
</div>
```

Quero o total da coluna `ltsa` entre uma data inicial e uma final.
Consegui o intervalo, mas não sei como somar.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```sql
SELECT SUM(t.ltsa)
FROM tb_abastece t
WHERE t.data BETWEEN '2019-01-20' AND '2019-01-30'
```

Obviamente, que isso só trará uma coluna como resultado, que é a soma. Você só pegará o resultado dessa coluna no `while`.

Comment: Olhando assim por cima me parece que 25/02/2014 vai estar entre esse intervalo aí, ao menos me parece formato de string. Datas no my até onde eu conheço (nao usei o 8) são yyyy-mm-dd, não?

Comment: @Bacco Arrumado.

Comment: Resta torcer pra coluna da Anna estar no formato data também, senão continua com problema, mesmo com as conversões (mas isso só com uma edição na pergunta por parte de quem postou mesmo).

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo